# Как сгенерировать все вариации слова

Tags: c#

Есть слово `Hello`.

Есть список замен:

```
H-@
H-*
e-~
l-&
```

На выходе должно получиться

```
@ello
@~llo
@~&lo
@~&&o
@e&&o
....
```

Т.е. надо перебрать все возможные вариации замен. Подскажите примерный алгоритм как это сделать. Можно псевдокодом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обычный перебор

```
private static Dictionary<char, char> _map = new Dictionary<char, char>()
{
    {'H', '@'},
    {'e', '~'},
    {'l', '&'},
};

public void Replace(char[] array, int index = 0){
    if (index >= array.Length) {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(array));
        return;
    }

    char c = array[index];

    Replace(array, index+1);
    if (_map.ContainsKey(c)) {
        array[index] = _map[c];
        Replace(array, index+1);
        array[index] = c;
    }
}
```

как использовать

```
Replace("Hello".ToCharArray());
```

Вывод

```
Hello
Hel&o
He&lo
He&&o
H~llo
H~l&o
H~&lo
H~&&o
@ello
@el&o
@e&lo
@e&&o
@~llo
@~l&o
@~&lo
@~&&o
```

**UPD**

Когда несколько значений в маппинге

```
private static Dictionary<char, char[]> _map = new Dictionary<char, char[]>()
{
    {'H', new []{'@', '*'}},
    {'e', new []{'~'}},
    {'l', new []{'&'}},
};

public void Replace(char[] array, int index = 0)
{
    if (index >= array.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(array));
        return;
    }

    char c = array[index];

    Replace(array, index + 1);
    if (_map.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        foreach (var r in _map[c])
        {
            array[index] = r;
            Replace(array, index + 1);
        }
        array[index] = c;
    }
}
```

Вызов

```
Replace("Hello".ToCharArray());
```

Вывод

```
Hello
Hel&o
He&lo
He&&o
H~llo
H~l&o
H~&lo
H~&&o
@ello
@el&o
@e&lo
@e&&o
@~llo
@~l&o
@~&lo
@~&&o
*ello
*el&o
*e&lo
*e&&o
*~llo
*~l&o
*~&lo
*~&&o
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ) а если у меня две замены с одинаковым ключом?

Comment: H-@
H-*    вот так например

Comment: Обновил ответ .

Comment: ) как всегда на высоте всё!