# Возможные комбинации элементов без повторений

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Задача состоит в следующем:
Имеется словарь где каждому числу соответствуют буквы, на которые это число можно заменить.
Нужно найти все возможные комбинации такие, что бы каждому числу соответствовала уникальная буква.

Изначально использовал функции библиотеки itertools, и неправильные варианты(где одна буква присваивается сразу нескольким числам) убирал с помощью проверки размера массива и соответственного множества(set), но время работы программы меня выходит очень большим.

Есть предположение, что нужно использовать рекурсию и тем самым перебрать все возможные варианты без повторений, но, к сожалению, в рекурсии не силён(

Пример:

```
data = {
  1 : ["a", "b", "c"],
  2 : ["b", "d", "k"],
  3 : ["c", "d", "l"]
}

# code

res = [
  {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'},
  {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'd'},
  {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'l'},
  {1: 'a', 2: 'd', 3: 'c'},
  {1: 'a', 2: 'd', 3: 'l'},
  {1: 'a', 2: 'k', 3: 'c'},
  {1: 'a', 2: 'k', 3: 'd'},
  {1: 'a', 2: 'k', 3: 'l'},
  {1: 'b', 2: 'd', 3: 'c'},
  {1: 'b', 2: 'd', 3: 'l'},
  {1: 'b', 2: 'k', 3: 'c'},
  {1: 'b', 2: 'k', 3: 'd'},
  {1: 'b', 2: 'k', 3: 'l'},
  {1: 'c', 2: 'b', 3: 'd'},
  {1: 'c', 2: 'b', 3: 'l'},
  {1: 'c', 2: 'd', 3: 'l'},
  {1: 'c', 2: 'k', 3: 'd'},
  {1: 'c', 2: 'k', 3: 'l'}
]
```

В самой задаче количество цифр необязательно должно быть три, код выше дан как пример.

Comment: Так а сколько у вас всего чисел и сколько вариантов на каждое число? Там нужно подумать, возможно быстрее будет действительно перебирать варианты по уровням и отсекать неподходящие варианты быстрее, досрочно завершая циклы. Если у вас фиксированное число цифр, то может быть вообще проще в явном виде такое число вложенных циклов написать, каково число цифр, и сделать в каждом досрочное завершение по `break`, если буквы наложились. Но в целом задача может быть и нерешаемой за обозримое время, если это подбор длинного пароля или ещё что-то вроде того.

Comment: когда то решал подобное, правда на сишарпе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1023626/179763

Comment: по идее, если у вас всего 3 числа, то можно обойтись и 3 циклами (один вложен в другой)